# Java Comparable and TreeSet

Tags: java, comparable, treeset

Why do objects put in a TreeSet have to implement the Comparable interface?
I'm trying to create a TreeSet containing some objects of my own class but ClassCastException is thrown when I try to add objects in the set.

Comment: A tree set works by constructing a binary tree. In order to place objects in a binary tree, they need to be compared with the root node and each branch node they encounter (to see which side of the tree they need to go on). You can use a HashSet instead of a TreeSet if you'd rather implement `hash()` than `compareTo()`.

Comment: You can't put items in a `TreeSet` without knowing how to compare them.

Comment: "*Why do objects put in a TreeSet have to implement the Comparable interface?*" - [They do not have to](https://ideone.com/3J1Kya). --- We need to provide some kind of order since [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeSet.html) implements [`SortedSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SortedSet.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeSet.html) is an ordered implementation of [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html).  Specifically, `TreeSet` implements [`NavigableSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NavigableSet.html) and [`SortedSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SortedSet.html), both sub-interfaces of `Set`.

## `Comparable`

When `TreeSet`'s values are iterated they are returned in the order defined by the object's class.  This can be useful when the objects in question have some natural concept of order - i.e. some values are 'less than' or 'more than' other values (e.g. dates).

In Java, the way to define the ordering of objects of a given class is by having that class implement [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html).

If you don't care about the ordering (which is often the case) you can use `HashSet` instead.

Alternatively, if you care about the order in which elements were *added* (but not their 'natural' order) you can use `LinkedHashSet`.

## `Comparator`

Finally, you might sometimes be interested in a set with a guaranteed iteration order (which is not the order the elements were added) but which is *not* the natural order of the objects defined by `compareTo`.  When this happens you can use the [constructor for `TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeSet.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.util.Comparator)) which takes an explicit [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html).  This comparator than defines the ordering (e.g. for iteration) for that *specific* set, which can be different from the natural order - if the objects have one, which they don't have to when using this constructor.